# Is there a way to use a bitmap or glide rather than a drawable image in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: mpandroidchart

```
int[] moodIconRes = {
            R.drawable.ic_emoticon_01, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_02, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_03,
            R.drawable.ic_emoticon_04, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_05, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_06,
            R.drawable.ic_emoticon_07, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_08, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_09,
            R.drawable.ic_emoticon_10, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_11, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_12
    };
```

Right now I am using it as a drawable.

private void setData1(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap) {
ArrayList entries = new ArrayList<>();

```
    int totalCount = 0; // 총 기분 수 (전체, 올해, 이번달마다 달라지는 값이므로 호출마다 초기화)
    maxMoodIndex = -1;  // 제일 많은 기분 종류
    maxCount = -1;      // 제일 많은 기분의 개수
    colors.clear();     // 파이차트를 구성할 색깔배열 clear (전체, 올해, 이번달마다 달라지는 값이므로 clear 필요)

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        if(hashMap.containsKey(i)) {
            count = hashMap.get(i);
            setMoodCount(i, count);
            totalCount += count;
            addColor(i);                // 기분 종류에 맞게 색깔 설정
            entries.add(new PieEntry(
                    count,
                    "",
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), moodIconRes[i])
            ));
        } else {
            setMoodCount(i, count);     // 개수 0
        }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a way to call it in the form of a bitmap or r.id.imageview rather than a drawable image in this part. I'd appreciate it if someone could give me an idea.

Comment: There is no such function nor constructor, you may wrap another class which derived from Entry to accept bitmp or resource id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BitmapDrawable

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```